# What's up with Sasazuka always getting sent to stand in the hallway?

Tags: strawberry-marshmallow

There doesn't seem to be noticeable tension between the class teacher and student Sasazuka (dark haired boy in white shirt), but he gets sent to stand in the hallway far too often without apparent reason. Is there some backstory to that?

[image]

Comment: To my best knowledge, there is _not_ any backstory to him in the original comic books.  He is getting sent to the hallway, I suppose, because the author finds it funny and hopes the readers will do so.

Comment: @Pteromys I guess you could post that as an answer.

Comment: Certainly.  As a side note, the author includes such jokes hard to understand especially later in the comic series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original comic books do not contain any backstory to his getting sent to the hallway (to my best knowledge).  Presumably, the author finds it funny for Sasazuka to be sent in the hallway for nothing, and hopes the readers will do so.